# Backslash is printing while writing id to mongoDb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am passing `id` from *angular js* to *nodejs server* in the following manner:
`formData.append("proId", JSON.stringify($scope.pid));`

I am also able to retrieve `id` on the server-side, but when I am posting that to *MongoDB*, it adding `back-shlahes` to id. 
*For example:*

`"\"5a0fc8ad4a9a9c2cd81a8853\""`, it shoulnot contain `\`  & extra `"` commas.
Why this is hapening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `JSON.stringify` does to a string:

```
→ node -pe 'JSON.stringify("5a0fc8ad4a9a9c2cd81a8853")'
"5a0fc8ad4a9a9c2cd81a8853"
```

You probably need to `JSON.parse` it on the server side.

```
→ node -pe 'JSON.parse("\"5a0fc8ad4a9a9c2cd81a8853\"")'
5a0fc8ad4a9a9c2cd81a8853
```

Or don't JSON encode the variable in the first place.